# How can we accessing array data in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

i have a problems in MIPS, i read a line in file then split the string to an array of integer values , finally i get an array with those number 100,5,20,-8,2.  i want to print the value a[4]=2 to a file.I read a link that give me an instruction about how we can access the value 2 at position 4 http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~xujie/cs447/AccessingArray.htm . i try my code

```
output: .asciiz "output.txt"

        #open file
            li $v0, 13       
            la $a0,output     
            li $a1, 1        
            li $a2, 0
        #accessing array
                la $t3,buffer  //access my array name buffer
                li $t5,4     //$t5=4
                add $t5,$t5,$t5
                add $t5,$t5,$t5
                add $t1,$t5,$t3 
    //write to file
        li $v0, 15       
        move $a0, $s6     
        move $a1, $t1
        li $a2, 4 //buffer length 
        syscall  
    //close
    li $v0, 16       
    move $a0, $s6     
    syscall  
But when i check my file ,nothing happend in my file. What happended ? Thanks for your help
```

Comment: You're using `$s6` without initializing it. And you're never actually performing the `open` syscall (13).

Comment: no in my code ,i already initialize s6, i cant write 500 code lines here. And i has syscall in my code too ,i just miss it here

Comment: I don't see how we're supposed to help finding problems in your code when you've removed important parts of the code you've posted. If you don't want to post 500 lines of code, then put together a minimal example that reproduces the issue.